# Где правильней выводить сообщение в консоль, в функции или в функции, которая многократно использует первую?

Tags: функции, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

Добрый день.

Есть игра "Камень-Ножницы-Бумага".

Вкратце, написал так:

```
* compChoice() //возвращает рандомно "камень", "ножницы", или "бумагу" в строковом значении.
* userChoice() //prompt запрашивает у пользователя значение и возвращает также "камень", "ножницы" или "бумагу" в строковом значении.
* resultOfOneGame(user, comp) // принимает то, что выбрал компьютер и то, что выбрал пользователь. возвращает, допустим, строку 'user', если победил пользователь или 'comp', если победил компьютер.
```

Нужно написать игру в бесконечном цикле (пусть будет наз-ся playGame()). Игра будет завершаться при нажатии кнопки "Отмена" и выдавать результат **всей игры**. Например:

```
"10 раундов сыграно, победил Компьютер".
```

На каждой итерации также нужно выводить в консоль сообщение о том кто выиграл данный раунд. Например:

```
"Раунд №2, победил Пользователь".
```

Функция playGame() содержит бесконечный цикл, выход из него и последующие действия после цикла.

```
В течение итерации:

    Вызов user = userChoice();
        Если пользователь нажал "Отмена", то цикл прерывается.
    Вызов comp = compChoice();
    Вызов resultOfOneGame(user, comp);

Вывести строку со статистикой по всей игре.
```

После цикла необходимо дать статистику (кол-во раундов, победитель). Но в течении игры после каждой итерации также необходимо в консоль выводить **кто победил в данном раунде**.

**Внимание, вопрос**.

Где правильней выводить результат в консоль:

в функции resultOfOneGame или в самой функции playGame()?
Если в консоль сообщения будут выводиться прямо из функции resultOfOneGame(), то не нужен возврат из нее (return 'user' или return 'comp').
Если в консоль будут выводиться сообщения из функции, то проверять придется не в самой функции resultOfOneGame(), а в функции playGame().
Требований никаких не стоит (например нет требования что должно приходить из функции resultOfOneGame() - строка в консоль или какое-то значение типа true или 'user win'.

Вопрос немного абстрактный и подразумевает "чем руководствоваться, золотой серединой, ранней оптимизацией или строго требованиям?".
Игра написана в обоих вариантах. Ответ нужен в образовательных целях.
Программирование изучаю сам, надеюсь на ответ, чтобы не начать быдлокодить.
Ниже привел конкретные примеры на JavaScript:

```
//Вариант 1
var resultOfOneGame = function() {
    //some code
    return winner;
}

var playGame = function() {
  //some code
  if (winner === user) {
      console.log(user, ' wins');
      userWins++;
  } else if (winner === comp) {
      console.log(comp, ' wins');
      compWins++;
  } else {
      deadHeat++;
      console.log(' friendship wins');
  }
}

//Вариант 2
var resultOfOneGame = function() {
    //some code
    console.log(winner, ' is win');
    return winner;
}

var playGame = function() {
  //some code
  if (winner === user) {
      userWins++;
  } else if (winner === comp) {
      compWins++;
  } else {
      deadHeat++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Принципиальной разницы нет, вопрос предпочтений. Лично я всегда из функции возвращаю значения, а если нужен какой-либо вывод - делаю его на основе этих значений